# Search / Answer sort order preference

Tags: feature-request, sorting, preferences

In both Question/Answer Searches, and Answers to Question, there is sort metrics (i.e., `Active`, `Oldest`, `Votes`)

I realise that the URL is appended with the sort order when clicking on the various options (Helpful for [browser search options](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Browser%27s-Default-Search-Engine#Google_Chrome), for example), but not so much for a default preference when just using the SE UI.

Though I couldn't find any previous questions about this (surprising, but am probably wrong), has any consideration been put into making this an option in each user's preferences?